# Как сделать окно активным? Python

Tags: python

У меня есть несколько (10-12) окон с одинаковым названием процесса.
Их айди я сохраняю в глобальный массив pid_list.
Далее мне нужно по очереди делать эти окна активными и выполнять там определенные задачи.
Как я могу сделать их активными через pid?

```
def main():
   for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == MY_PROCESS_NAME:
            print(proc)
            pid = proc.pid
            pid_list.append(pid)
            activate_window_by_pid(pid)

def activate_window_by_pid(pid):
...
```

Comment: ОС какая? В иксах проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для активации окна по его PID можно использовать библиотеку `win32gui` и функцию `SetForegroundWindow`. Вот пример кода:

```py
import win32gui

def activate_window_by_pid(pid):
    try:
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, None)  # Должно вернуть hwnd последнего активного окна
        while hwnd:
            cur_pid = win32gui.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)[1]
            if cur_pid in pid_list:
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
                break
            hwnd = win32gui.GetWindow(hwnd, win32con.GW_HWNDNEXT)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка:", e)
```

В этом примере мы используем функцию `FindWindow`, чтобы найти hwnd последнего активного окна. Затем мы перебираем окна с помощью функции `GetWindow`, начиная с этого hwnd, и проверяем, является ли PID окна из списка `pid_list`. Если да, мы активируем его, вызывая функцию `SetForegroundWindow`.

Убедитесь, что вы установили пакет `pywin32`, чтобы использовать эту библиотеку. Вы можете установить его с помощью команды `pip install pywin32`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: спасибо. я пользовался win32gui библиотекой ранее, но мне постоянно выкидывало access denied.
перешел на pywinauto